# transitive closure in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

a = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]])

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(a, create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())

T = nx.transitive_closure(G)

print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(T))
```

The transitive closure lacks the expected self loops. Why?  (The documentation link does not work.)  By "expected", I mean "according to standard definitions", such as the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).  I anticipate that a different definition is being used, but what is it?

Comment: The link in the documentation is broken because it looks like David Eppstein (the author of the file linked to) has converted PADS directory to a git repository.  If you want to check out the file referenced you can clone the repository: `git clone http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/.git`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an error of implementation. The docstring is clear on the definition: "a graph G+ = (V,E+) such that for all v,w in V there is an edge (v,w) in E+ if and only if there is a non-null path from v to w in G." Self-loops qualify under this definition.

The algorithm boils down to, after making TC a copy of given G,

```
for v in G:
    TC.add_edges_from((v, u) for u in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=v)
                      if v != u)
```

So the self-loops never get added because of `if v != u`. The reason for exclusion is that the output of `dfs_preorder_nodes` will begin with `v` (the source) no matter what edges are there, and of course we don't want to add a loop `(v, v)` just because of that. But as a side effect of relying on `dfs_preorder_nodes`, the algorithm never gets to determine whether  `v` itself is reachable from `v` via a **non-null path**.

So, to obtain the transitive closure in the usual sense, we need to add loops `(v, v)` for each node `v`  that lies on a cycle. Like this:

```
T = nx.transitive_closure(G)

for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G):
    T.add_edges_from((v, v) for v in cycle)
```

In matrix form, `T` is now

```
[[4. 2. 2.]
 [2. 4. 2.]
 [2. 2. 4.]]
```

Loops got added multiple times. If you care about multiplicities (although I don't really see what edge multiplicities are expected of a transitive closure), something like this could be done to prevent multiple addition of edges:

```
cycles = frozenset().union(*[frozenset(cycle) for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G)])
T.add_edges_from((v, v) for v in cycles)
```

Then `T` is

```
[[1. 2. 2.]
 [2. 1. 2.]
 [2. 2. 1.]]
```